# remote SSH connection to a local system

Tags: router, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

To enable remote `SSH` to a local system what router configuration is required?

Basically, just forward port 22 to a specific `IP` or `MAC` address through the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, you'll need for open the port on your router for the specific IP address and also enable the port to listen on the host via the local firewall assuming that it is active.